# Regex to clean-up ids with spaces and extract from string

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have strings like this with embedded ids.  The Id should be 9 continuous digits but it is often written like this.  I want to extract just the id and **sanitize** so its 9 continuous digits

```
ID OF 20067 8641 IS RELATED 
WITH40106117 7.
AND 301287 532 
OR 301 287 532
```

This regex accounts for the first and third example above **(replacing with \1\2)** I can't figure out the second and fourth example.

```
.*[\s]([0-9]{1,9})\s([0-9]{1,9}).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/zEhSsy/1/

I'm writing this is postgres using **regexp_replace** but just a regex solution will do.

Comment: does remaining text contains any digit ?

Comment: yes, I should have included variation such as this: '957 SMITH OR 301 287 532'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just spaces between the digits, you may remove them and extract sequence of 9 digits.

```
with t as --test data
(
select s::text from 
( VALUES ( 'ID OF 20067 8641 IS RELATED'), 
('WITH40106117 7.'),
('AND 301287 532 '),
('OR 301 287 532') ) as s 
) --test data ends 
select  s,SUBSTRING ( replace(s,' ','') FROM '\d{9}' ) as id from t;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=013c91a80e370c2232f4f80f3f8b0862)

Comment: great thanks - didn't know you could replace with substring - this handles other variations like '957 SMITH OR 301 287 532'